# What unicode-friendly text editor would you recommend for Windows?

Tags: localization, editor

I work on a lot of Asian Language localization projects, and am looking for a powerful text editor with the following features:

1) Unicode support
2) Find in Files
3) Replace in Files
4) Regular expressions
5) Multiline find/replace
6) Built-in diff

I am currently using NotePad++, but it doesn't really support unicode in its find-in-files tool, which is a deal-breaker. EmEditor looks promising, but it doesn't have multi-line find/replace.

Anyone working with Chinese, Japanese, or Korean files have a text editor that they like, free or commercial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/). It's written in Java, which has language-level Unicode support. I haven't confirmed that it has all those features you listed, but I'd be surprised if it did not.

Answer (score 2):

I use [UniRed](http://www.esperanto.mv.ru/UniRed/ENG/) for Unicode-intensive stuff.  (I don't use it as a general purpose editor though: jEdit).  UniRed displays the hex value for the current glyph in the lower screen, which is really handy (even for ASCII).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a page that describes using [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) with Chinese language files: http://blog.wensheng.com/2007/05/vim-gvim-utf8-and-chinese-in-windows-xp.html

Disclaimer: I don't actually work with Asian languages, but Vim is the first thing that comes to mind when I think of a featureful and internationalized editor.

Answer (score 0):

[Ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html) is my favorite text editor and it is advertised as having good Unicode support

http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/unicode.html.

It has the find / replace / regex features you're looking for as well as almost every other feature I have ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

#### [SciTE](http://scintilla.sourceforge.net/SciTETranslation.html)

http://scintilla.sourceforge.net/SciTETranslation.html

~ ~ ~

Relevant new features (unicode) of [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaHistory.html)'s (*the library which the SciTE editor is built upon*) recent release notes:

- Released on 18 October 2008.

  - Scintilla on Windows can interpret keys as Unicode even when a narrow character window with SCI_SETKEYSUNICODE.
  - Notification sent when autocompletion cancelled.
  - Assembler lexer works with non-ASCII text.
  - CSS lexer updated and works with non-ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend EditPadPro (http://www.editpadpro.com). Aside from full Unicode support, it has one of the best regex engines built-in (it's from JGSoft, the makers of RegexBuddy (which incidentally integrates perfectly into EditPadPro)). You'll need RegexBuddy for the Find/Replace in files feature, everything else from your list is covered by EditPadPro itself.

I've switched from UltraEdit to EditPadPro a few months ago precisely because of its superior regex engine (UltraEdit's Perl regex engine has a few annoying bugs especially concerning multi-line find/replace operations).

A portable version that installs on any USB stick is included for free.

Jan Goyvaerts, EPP's creator, is a Belgian living in Thailand, so you can be pretty sure he knows his way around Asian languages.